# Passing Object reference,Not getting expected result.

Tags: java, object, static

on passing object reference to static method m1() why it does not become null and why last statement doesn't give errror. Output is X

```
 class I {
        private String name;
        public String name() {            
            return name;
        }
        public I (String s) {            
            name = s;            
        }
    }

    class J {
        public static void m1 (I i){
            i = null;
        }
        public static void main (String[] arg)
        {
            I i = new I("X");
            m1(i);
            System.out.print(i.name());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to have a sensible *title* and then text within the question. Questions which are *just* code are pretty poor...

Comment: (I've performed an edit to make things somewhat more reasonable, but you should edit it further yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is pass by value so scope of `i` is limited to m1()

```
public static void m1 (I i){ // i is copied from i which is in main method but it is another variable whose scope lies within m1() only

    i = null;  // original i in main lies in main() method scope

}
```

If you change name of `i` in method m1(), confusion will be lesser like :

```
public static void m1 (I iObj){ 
    iObj = null;  // i in main() method still points to Object

}
```

Comment: so method is either static or instance doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: @user1617840 : we said methods, so applicable to all methods.

Answer (score 1):

Java is [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) (Read second answer in the link specially)

`I i` scope of `i` is limited to method `m1` only.

In execution it looks something like:

```
`I i` in `m1()` points to `null` reference

I i method reference still points to `new I("X");`
```

Answer (score 1):

Java uses *pass by value* exclusively. Changing the value of `i` within `m1` *only* changes that parameter's value. It doesn't do *anything* to the variable `i` within `main`.

What may confuse you - it certainly confuses plenty of other people - is that although the arguments are passed by value, if the type of the parameter is a class, then that value is a *reference*... and indeed the value of the `i` variable in each case is a reference. That reference is still passed by value - the value of the argument is directly copied as the initial value of the parameter. However, if instead of changing the parameter itself you make a change to the object that the parameter value *refers* to, that's a different matter:

```
void foo(StringBuilder builder) {
    builder.append("Hello");
}

void bar() {
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
    foo(x);
    System.out.println(x); // Prints Hello
}
```

See the [Java tutorial on passing information to a method or constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details.

Comment: so method is either static or instance doesn't matter in this case?